# Keycloak for securing microservice to microservice call

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, openid-connect, keycloak

my first question is how to ask itself :-) cause i am a little bit lost.

My idea is the following:

Having several microservices (spring boot apps) which could interact with each other and also could be called from outside directly. So i think it would be a good idea ot secure them. The idea for the first step of having them called each other is using client authentication. 
So i created a realm and several client configs and add the client config for each rest endpoint to the rest template as ClientCredentials

```
class MyRestTemplate(
        details: ClientCredentialsResourceDetails,
        private val baseUrl: String
) : OAuth2RestTemplate(details)
```

and having a provider

```
@Bean
    fun restTemplate(): MyRestTemplate{
        return MyRestTemplate(details(), config.baseUrl)
    }


    private fun details(): ClientCredentialsResourceDetails {
        val details = ClientCredentialsResourceDetails()
        details.grantType = "client_credentials"
        details.accessTokenUri = "${config.accessTokenUri}"

        details.clientId = config.clientId
        details.clientSecret = config.clientSecret

        return details
    }
```

But when i call MS A from MS B i get a 302 Redirect .. So my question is ...

Is there something wrong with the idea itself? 
Or how to deal with that?
Are there any best practices?

Would it be a better idea, to use e.g. a Ingress Controller the Kubernetes world for doing the authentication from the outside world?

Thx in advance

Comment: Have you find a solution to this problem ? Are you still relying only on KeyCloack ?

Comment: Yes i still relying on keycloak. But switched to Micronaut, configuration is much more easier.

Comment: https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/09/21/micronaut-oauth2-and-security-with-keycloak/